# Reference on MITxPRO Applications of Quantum Computing Professional Certificate Program

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance

Recently I found out the *Applications of Quantum Computing Professional Certificate Program* that MITxPRO is offering for people interested in quantum computing. I saw that it is consisted of four courses that can be done independently or as a whole program. [This](https://mitxpro.mit.edu/courses/course-v1:MITxPRO+QCx4+2T2018/about) is the link for the course.

I am especially interested in just the last one of such four courses, but I do not know if it would be necessary to take the other ones so that I could do such course.

That's why I was wondering if someone here has started this course, and so if there is someone, if he could give an insight about which is the level required for taking such courses, the time required in order to complete the homework and his opinion about the course in general. Also it would be interesting to hear if you think that taking all courses should be necessary (although I am aware of the fact that just one of the courses has been given, so this would be a subjective opininon).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I signed up for this series because I was interested in the 2nd and 3rd courses.

There are a lot of students from different backgrounds so I think that limits the depth of what the instructors can cover. The introductory course was too easy in terms of content, however useful in the form of industry perspectives and getting to know 'who is doing what' in hardware. My fear is that the remaining courses will be a bit too simple/general.

The bulk of the time is spent watching videos. I set the speed to 1.25x or else it's just a bit too slow for me. You could complete the entire course in a weekend.

Taking all the courses is absolutely not necessary but you do get a nice certificate at the end.

Oct 31, 2018 Update

I've finished all 4 courses and have to say the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th courses were great. They went into a reasonable amount of depth in the topics. I'd recommend the series to anyone starting out. If you're already familiar with the basics then maybe skip the first course.

Jan 2, 2020 Update

Since I received a few upvotes on this answer recently, I thought I would add a bit more information. The 4 course certificate program has since been split into two two-course programs. Quantum Computing Fundamentals and Quantum Computing Realities. My comments above still stand. Skip the fundamentals course if you're already familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 3):

Content wise very similar course but different name **Quantum Information Science I** (three parts - part 1, 2, and 3) and **Quantum Information Science II**  were $49 per course as verified certified learning outcome - a series of 3 courses + 1 more extra course on edX. Now the course has been taken down; at least no more new enrollments, and MITx Pro is offering it for \$2250 + \$2250 = \$4500. This is 20 times higher for the same course.

I see there would be a number of other MOOCs coming soon. One such is from St Petersberg State University - Introduction to Quantum Computing, but the English version is very poor in quality of content compared to the Russian version on Coursera. However, there is a course from TU Delft on edX, and also one from Keio University at FutureLearn. These options could be looked at; same content but at lower price.

PS: I am coming up with a course on Udemy and also maybe on Coursera with IBM Qiskit open network free version. Stay tuned for it.

Edit-2: Adding edX course links cited above.

1. **Quantum Information Science I**

   - 1.1) Quantum Information Science I, Part 1 https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-information-science-i-part-1
   - 1.2) Quantum Information Science I, Part 2 https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-information-science-i-part-2
   - 1.3) [Quantum Information Science I, Part 3  https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-information-science-i-part-3
2. **Quantum Information Science II: Advanced quantum algorithms and information theory**
   https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-information-science-ii-advanced-quantum-al

Comment: I was in the first cohort and since then, while the certificate program has gone on sale with a 10% off code, it has never been $49.